# Not able to get full name using regex

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I’m having the below string…

```
let string = “[@he man:user:123] [@super man:user:456] [@bat man:user:789]”
```

I apply a regex to get just the names like so…

```
 func findMentionText2() -> [String] {
    var arr_hasStrings:[String] = []
    let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(@[a-zA-Z0-9_\\p{N}]*)", options: [])
    if let matches = regex?.matches(in: self, options:[], range:NSMakeRange(0, self.count)) {
      for match in matches {
        arr_hasStrings.append(NSString(string: self).substring(with: NSRange(location:match.range.location, length: match.range.length )))
      }
    }
    return arr_hasStrings
  }
```

And if I do `let hashString = string.findMentionText()`, I get `[“@he”, “@super”, “@bat”]`

But what I wanted was the full name like this…

```
[“@he man”, “@super man”, “@bat man”]
```

What regex do I need to use for that..? Also how can I get the id’s associated with each user..?

**EDIT 1** **ADDING EACH VALUE TO AN ARRAY USING TYPEALIAS**

I declared an array and typealias like so...

```
typealias UserTag = (name: String, id: String)
var userTagList = [UserTag]()
```

And then, added them to an array and printed out each detail like so...

```
let hashString2 = string.findMentionText2()

    for unit in hashString2 {
      let user: UserTag = (name: unit.first!, id: unit.last!)
      userTagList.append(user)

    }

    //EACH DETAIL PRINTED HERE
    for value in userTagList {
        print(value.id)
        print(value.name)
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may extract these substrings using

```
"(@[^\\]\\[:]+):user:(\\w+)"
```

It matches and captures into Group 1 a `@` char and then 1+ chars other than `]`, `[` and `:`, then matches `:user:` and then captures into Group 2 any 1+ word chars. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9p8KKn/1).

As an alternative, you may use

```
"(@\\w+(?: \\w+)*):user:(\\w+)"
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9p8KKn/2). I use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_\\p{N}]` as `\w` matches any letter, digit and `_`, too.  The pattern will match and capture into Group 1 a `@` char, then 1+ word chars (letters, digits or `_`) and then 0 or more repetitions of a space and then 1+ word chars, then it will match `:user:` and then will capture into Group 2 any 1+ word chars.

If you want to match any whitespace, replace the literal space with `\\s`.

Here is the Swift demo:

```
let string = "[@he man:user:123] [@super man:user:456] [@bat man:user:789]"
extension String {
  func findMentionText() -> [[String]] {
    let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(@\\w+(?: \\w+)*):user:(\\w+)", options: [])
    if let matches = regex?.matches(in: self, options:[], range:NSMakeRange(0, self.count)) {
      return matches.map { match in
            return (1..<match.numberOfRanges).map {
                let rangeBounds = match.range(at: $0)
                guard let range = Range(rangeBounds, in: self) else {
                    return ""
                }
                return String(self[range])
            }
      }
   } else {
       return []
   }
 }
}
let hashString = string.findMentionText()
print(hashString)
// => [["@he man", "123"], ["@super man", "456"], ["@bat man", "789"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Wiktor Stribiżew..your answer does give me the full names in an array. But I wanted to get the userid's also without the "user" tag...ie. maybe something like this...[“@he man“:123, “@super man“:456, “@bat man“:789]

Comment: @asd2 Just let me clarify: you want an array like `[["@he man", "456"], ["@super man", "456"]...]`?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Just one more concern @Wiktor Stribiżew..hope u won't mind.. I have added each element to an array using typealias and printed them out. I have edited the question with that change. But in one place I did this `let user: UserTag = (name: unit.first!, id: unit.last!)` Instead of doing `array.first` & `array.last`, I would like to add the `name` and `id` to typealias and then to the array in the regex function itself. But how to add the `name` & `id` to the array from the regex itself, I can't figure out..

Answer (score 0):

Try with this: `(@[\\w ]+):user:(\\d+)`

You have a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/WAyx91/3/).

The username will be on the first capturing group. And the Id will be on the second capturing group.

**Explanation:**

```
(              # begin of first capturing group
    @          # literal @
    [          # begin of character class: It must be:
       \\w     # a-z, 0-9, underscore
       _       # and spaces (i'm using an underscore here just for make it clear)
    ]          # end of character class
    +          # repeated 1 or more
)              # end of first capturing group
:user:         # literal :user:
(\\d+)         # begin of second capturing group, 1 or more digits, end of second capturing group
```